# Bathroom ceiling exhaust fan wiring

Tags: bathroom, switch, fans, exhaust

My bathroom exhaust fan/w light has a 4th cable which runs from the fan box to a switch for a strip of 5 lights above the sink. How do I make that connection? In other words, to which black and neutral wires in the fan/light box should I connect the black and neutral wires of the cable going to the switch?

Comment: You should consult the installation directions that came with the fan.

Comment: A photo slways helps

Comment: 4 cables.  As a guess one cable is power in.  Second cable is to another device.  Third cable is to the switch for the five lights.  The forth cable is to the switch for the fan/light.

Comment: Crip659, Thanks for your comment. Power in is one switch, and two switches are for the fan and light individually. Those are all I need to run the fan and light. However, this is a replacement fan and there was a 4th cable. I tried to label them all when I disassembled the old unit. However, the three wires from this 4th cable did not seem to be connected to the three caps used to connect the various wires. I discovered this cable runs to the switch for the lights over the sink. The fan and its light work fine, but the GFCI is not permitting the switch or the lights over the sink to come on.